# importing third party library es6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, plotly

Im trying to import plotly into my react app. 
Ive installed plotly with:

```
npm install plotly --save
```

Ive then tried importing in these different ways:

```
import * as Plotly from 'plotly'
import Ploty from 'plotly'
var Plotly = require('plotly')
```

Then I tried using plotly like this:

```
Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data)
```

But every import gives me this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Plotly.newPlot is not a function
```

Im really lost and cannot find the right way to import plotly or any other third party library. Every guide, article I followed says I should import like Ive already tried.

Comment: i think you are missing the user name and API Key. As per the npm webpage - https://www.npmjs.com/package/plotly , one must provide the same . var plotly = require('plotly')(username, apiKey). Also no api as `newPlot` indeed exist. You may want to use `plotly.plot`

Comment: Doesn't `require` need a bundler or packager? ES6 import syntax uses `import plotly from 'plotly';`

Comment: Sorry guys, turns out I tried using the wrong plotly. As Vincent said, I need plotly.js and not plotly. Thats why I was missing the API key and username, because I wasn't trying to use their api, I was trying to use their library.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Base on their [Gitub](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js) page, you need to install plotly.js and not potly. `npm install plotly.js`. After be sure to have a module loader correctly configurated to load it. Then you will be able to do `import Potly from 'plotly.js';`

Comment: You're a life saver! I feel so stupid for missing that. Im used to working with the plotly cdn and I just couldn't figure out how to get it working with npm.